# how added R string in this script in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
fun propagate(
    throwable: Throwable?,
    noInternet: ((String?) -> Unit)? = null,
    noAuthorization: ((String?) -> Unit)? = null,
    unAvailable: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    defaultError: ((String) -> Unit)? = null,
    eofException: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    if (throwable is SocketException || throwable is UnknownHostException
        || throwable is SocketTimeoutException ) {
        noInternet?.invoke("No Internet Connection")
        return
    }
}
```

i want to call string in this script but error. how to resolve? thank you

error log in android studio :
Type mismatch.
Required:
String?
Found:
Int

Comment: What error? Do you have an error message you could post here?

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required:
String?
Found:
Int  (this is my error sir) huhuhu :(

Comment: We need to see more code... How do you initialize `nointernet`? Is that a `String`? If yes, you might have to use something like `getResources().getString(R.string.nointernet)`, otherwise it will return the id of that `String`, which might be an `Int` and the result would be your error...

Comment: yes sir like that this is my full code in above :)

Comment: fun propagate(
 throwable: Throwable?,
 noInternet: ((String?) -> Unit)? = null,
 noAuthorization: ((String?) -> Unit)? = null,
 unAvailable: (() -> Unit)? = null,
 defaultError: ((String) -> Unit)? = null,
 eofException: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
 if (throwable is SocketException ||
  throwable is UnknownHostException ||
  throwable is SocketTimeoutException
 ) {
  noInternet?.invoke("No Internet Connection")
  return
 }

Comment: i want replace no internet connection with call string

Answer (score 0):

Strings are texts in resources available via id (e.g. `R.string.error_no_internet`). They can be provided for different languages (by creating separate resource files).

In order to provide a proper String for a given id, the system must know the context information. This means you cannot just write `R.string.error_no_internet` and the system will replace it for you.

You must call a `getString(id: Int): String` method passing the required id for the String you want to get. Most of the time you will use a `Context` for this. See more examples below:

- `context.getString(R.string.error_no_internet)`
- `resources.getString(R.string.error_no_internet)`
- `getString(R.string.error_no_internet)`

You can call this in `App`, `Activity`, `Fragment` or `View`. Anywhere, where `Context` or `Resources` object is available.